# onClick ( execute ) event of qx.ui.basic.Image?

Tags: qooxdoo

Is there any onClick (execute) of `qx.ui.basic.Image` ?

```
var myImage = new qx.ui.basic.Image("myApp/image.png");
myImage.addListener("execute", function(e) {
  // some action
});
```

Qooxdoo prompts an error:

> There is no event handler for the event 'execute' on target

Is it a must to use a `qx.ui.basic.Button` with Image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want. If you want all the stuff like focusable and keyboard accessable, you have to make it a button. Still, you can easily remove the look of the button in the theme or by setting the decorator to null. If you don't need all that and only want a click event, you can listen instead of execute to click which will work as expected on images as well.

Comment: @MartinWittermann thanks for answering my question again. But how to listen instead of execute to click ? I thought my code was listening .

Comment: Read '...listen instead of "execute" to "click" ...' - meaning the event name.